# What does the Area Damage utility stat do?

Tags: diablo-iii

In my Paragon tab under utility, there's a stat called Area Damage. What exactly does this do?  Does it affect all my aoe skills, add aoe to my normal attacks, or add aoe to all my skills?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your inventory>details>offense you can see statistic called Area Damage.
Where it states :

> "**All attacks** have a 20% chance to also deal **X**% of the damage to
>   enemies within 10 yards"

Where **X** is "area damage" bonus gained from items and paragon levels(if skilled).

Each enemy that takes any damage from your hero,**whether from aoe,DOT or single target spell/attack**,will have 20% chance to deal X% of the damage it received in **10 yards radius around him**.
Making Area damage more effective when used with aoe spells on large groups.
[Source.](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/11884138502?page=1#19)

When triggered **area damage instances can't crit** on their own(no yellow numbers).
However if you made critical strike on target that triggered area damage then it **will splash X% of the critical damage you made**.

---

There is also possible naming title bug on this stat which could cause some confusion.It says "Area Damage Chance : X%" where the title should be just "Area Damage : X%" . Because the chance is static 20% and they used damage variable X.

[Here is an in-depth guide about area damage that was featured on official diablo 3 website.](http://bannedofgamers.com/index.php?AD/)

Comment: yea I saw that after I posted my question, but I still don't know what it does for aoe stuff.  I also wonder if its affected by proc rates.  Otherwise a DH with rapid fire would proc it a lot more than a DH using hungering arrow.

Comment: It probably works same as critical hit chance.Skills similar to rapid fire(high attack speed) are actually multiplying your crit chance with their own hidden proc value,resulting in lower chance to make critical hit with each arrow.

Comment: just an update.  I believe the general consensus amoung the community for AOE is that it treats an AOE spell as a single chance of of proccing.  For example, if I cast blizzard on a group of monsters, it has a 20% chance of proccing once on the first cast/hit of a monster under blizzard.  It doesn't proc on every hit or else blizzard would destroy everything in its path.

Comment: So 20%* 20% is like 4% extra damage. But multiplied by numbers of enemy affected it could be 20%-40% extra productivity.

Answer (score 0):

***Taken from the Diablo 3 forums (March 2014):***

- You have a 20% flat chance to cause X% amount of area damage to all enemies within 10 yards of your target.
- This area damage doesn't crit, but if your initial hit that caused area damage was a crit, then the area damage will have increased damage (like a crit but without the yellow numbers) since Area Damage is a certain % of the damage of the original hit.
- You can increase this area damage by X% amount with paragon levels and stats on items.
- The chance to cause area damage stays at the base flat rate of 20% and cannot be changed.
- Area damage works off of all skills that hit a target.
- If you have 100% area damage (possible with 50 paragon levels and items) and you crit something for lets say 3 million then you have 20% chance to deal 3 million damage to all enemies around that target.
- Barbarian DoT skills like Rend can proc multiple times over the duration of the skill.
- Demon Hunter piercing skills like Hungering Arrow can also proc multiple times.
- *Uncertain: I think the area damage only procs from your main hit on a target with any skill, but I could be wrong about that.*